# Pandas split on character and remove trailing values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove residual data that is identified with a '[' while keeping the first value.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'foo':['a','b[b7','c']})
print(df)
```

becomes:

```
0 a
1 b[b7
2 c
```

would like to have

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'foo':['a','b[b7','c']} )
df["foo"] = df["foo"].str.replace("(\[.*)","")
```

Here is the https://regex101.com/ explanation

```
1st Capturing Group (\[.*)
\[ matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)
.* matches any character (except for line terminators)
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

What this means is that it will look for a [ . If it finds one it will remove the [ and all characters after it.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.foo=df.foo.str[0]
df
Out[212]: 
  foo
0   a
1   b
2   c
```

Comment: what if the first value is ab[a ?

Comment: @GabrielA let us waiting for op

Comment: This is fine, but this would work only if we're dealing with single chars. Still, voted.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're looking for `str.split` + `str[0]` -

```
df

      foo
0    test
1  foo[b7
2    ba[r

df.foo.str.split('[').str[0]

0    test
1     foo
2      ba
Name: foo, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[x.split('[')[0] for x in ['a','b[b7','c']]})
print(df)
```